# More efficient way to customize your borders in html

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I am seeking for better way to arrange my borders.
Currently I have something like this, but I feel there must be some better and quick solution to this.

My Code:

```
<style>
td.left{
border-top-style:solid;
border-left-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
}

td.right{
border-top-style:solid;
border-right-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
}

td.updown{
border-top-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
}

td.left2{
border-left-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
}

td.right2{
border-right-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
}

td.updown2{
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
}

td.finish{
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
}

table {
border-style:none; 
padding:1px; 
margin:0px; 
border-spacing: 0px; 
border: 0pxborder: ;
width:850px;
}
</style>
```

I have created classes with each specific side to be displayed for each different purposes.

Here is the body part of the code, I have used class "left" for 1st row and "left2" for 2nd row, this is due to if I use both rows with "left" then second row will have thicker line between 1st row and 2nd row.
In this table I want to make lines between a specific column to disappear or appear but struggling to find shorter code to do so.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="149" class="left"> For testing 1</td>
      <td width="312" class="updown"><input type="text" /></td>
      <td width="172" class="left"> For testing 2</td>
      <td width="204" class="right"> <input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left2">For testing 3</td>
      <td class="right2" colspan="3"><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left2" colspan="2">For testing 4</td>
      <td class="finish" colspan="2"><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a character-saving solution with `border-collapse: collapse;`

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aj4yw/)**

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>For testing 1</span><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><span>For testing 2</span><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span>For testing 3</span><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>For testing 4</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 850px;
}

span {
float: left;
width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: It is nice and neat, but I just realised, this will only work if "For testing 1" and "For testing 3" have same character numbers. If "For testing 3" is changed to something with different character number then textbox next to it will no longer line up with upper row.

Comment: I edited it, now it works correctly, the span now has a fixed width

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it works around my border issue and solved my main purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is this:

```
td { 
    border:1px solid black; 
}

td.left{ 
    border-right-style:none; 
}
td.right{ 
    border-left:none; 
}
td.updown{ 
    border-left:none; 
    border-right:none; 
}
td.left2{ 
    border-top:none; 
    border-right:none; 
}
td.right2{ 
    border-left:none; 
    border-top:none; 
}
td.updown2{ 
    border-top:none; 
    border-left:none; 
    border-right:none; 
}
td.finish{ 
    border-top:none; 
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Cuyxh/

However, I would suggest using classes for each border in your HTML, for a more modular approach.

Example:

```
b-left, b-right, b-top, b-down { 
    border-color:black;
    border-width:1px;
}
b-left { 
    border-left-style:solid; 
}
b-top { 
    border-top-style:solid; 
}
b-right { 
    border-right-style:solid; 
}
b-bottom { 
    border-bottom-style:solid; 
}
```

And then adding these classes to your table cells. For example:

```
<td width="149" class="b-left b-top">For testing 1</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am able to shorten my code by taking out solid and 1px from each class. and for class, I guess if I make the class name as "bl,br,bt,bd" then I think it will be easier to use. Thanks for the advise.